# Electron GET request with saved session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, electron

I am trying to send a GET request to a website using net.request module after logging into the website manually in a BrowserWindow and persisting the session using the webPreferences.partition option per below. However, the net.request gives me back the login page instead of the landing page one would see if logged in, indicating it did not use the partition indicated (it fails too with the session option). Is this a bug or am I using it incorrectly?

```
// From main.js open browser window and login manually
let loginWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: 'Login Manually',
    show: show,
    webPreferences: {
        partition: 'persist:my-session-name'
    }
});

loginWindow.loadURL('https://my.internal.url/path');

// later in the main process, try to hit landing page or another endpoint using net.request and the same session
const net = require('electron').net;

const request = net.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://my.internal.url/path',
    // 'persist:my-session-name' was created by logging in manually earlier
    // Failes with 'persist:my-session-name' and 'my-session-name'
    partition: 'persist:my-session-name'
});

request.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`);

    response.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
    });

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });


});

request.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed one more parameter: `useSessionCookies`. Simply add it to your code like this:

```
const request = net.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://my.internal.url/path',
    partition: 'persist:my-session-name',
    useSessionCookies: true
});
```

For more options and details visit: [Electron.ClientRequest](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request#class-clientrequest)